# Reactjs - Changing JSON based on state

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

**SOLVED**:  Solution is on the bottom

I have a drop down menu that changes the current state of the component.  Something like this:

```
<select onChange={event => this.setState({typeofList: event.target.value})}>
  <option value="list.A">List A</option>
  <option value="list.B">List B</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that when I set the state it throws me an error as soon as I click on an item in the menu.  This because I have a function that changes the JSON I use for the list.  Here is a snippet of code:

JSON

```
const list = require("./list.json")
```

list.json is huge, but looks something like this:

```
{
    "A":{
        "objects":{
            "term":["ball"],
            "image":["./img/ball"]
        }
    },
    "B":{
        "objects":{
            "term":["stick"],
            "image":["./img/stick"]
        }
    },
}
```

State

```
constructor(props){
super(props)

        this.state={
            term:'',
            typeofList: list.A
        }
    }
```

Function that throws error

```
createArr(){
    let item = this.state.typeofList.split(/(\s)/)
    let arr = []
    for(var i=0;i<item.length;i++){
        if(/(\[(.*?)\]|\((.*?)\))/g.test(item[i])){
            arr.push(item[i])
        }
        for (var key in this.state.typeofList){
            for(var j=0;j<this.state.typeofList[key].term.length;j++){
                if (this.state.typeofList[key].term[j] === item[i]){
                    arr.push(item[i])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

The console says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".  This function works until I click another list to change the state.  I'm not really sure if this is good practice.  How should I be changing the list in the JSON?

**SOLUTION**:  I called the JSON object the wrong way.  What I did was assign `typeofList` to a string like this:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)

  this.state={
    term:'',
    typeofList: "A"
  }
}
```

And then called it using `[this.state.typeofList]` instead of just typing `this.state.typeofList`.  I can get keys by typing `list[this.state.typeofList][key]`

Comment: show a complete example.  Without knowing anything about when that code snippet runs in relation to the rendering snippet it is difficult to help you.

Comment: typeofList is just a string "list.A" ? isn't it?

Comment: There's no JSON involved here. Just JavaScript Objects. JSON is a format for who to express objects in a string, so unless you're talking about manipulating strings in JSON format, the incorrect tag/name is used here.

Comment: I have a JSON list. I have const list = require("./list.json") at the top.  "list.A" would be an object in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" because you have set the value of `this.state.typeofList[key]` to a string. Thus, `this.state.typeofList[key].term` becomes undefined.

`onChange={event => this.setState({typeofList: event.target.value})}`

event.target.value is a string

I'm guessing that you will need to update the value of `term` instead

Comment: The function works before the change in state.  I have a test function that logs `this.state.typeofList[key].term` to the console and it logs it properly.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your answer the first time.  I got it to work because `typeofList` was indeed defined as a string in my state constructor.  Therefore to call the JSON key I should have done something like `[this.state.typeofList][key]`.  Thank you for the help!